# Is modifying an object more than once in an expression through its name and through its reference well-defined?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, undefined-behavior

Hello I have a simple question: is modifying an object more than once in the same expression; once through its identifier (name) and second through a reference to it or a pointer that points at it Undefined Behavior?

```
int i = 1;
std::cout << i << ", " << ++i << std::endl; //1- Error. Undefined Behavior

int& refI = i;
std::cout << i << ", " << ++refI << std::endl; //2-  Is this OK?

int* ptrI = &refI; // ptrI point to the referred-to object (&i)

std::cout << i << ", " << ++*ptrI << std::endl; // 3 is this also OK?
```

- In the second it seems to work fine but I am confused about it because from what I've learned; a Reference is just an alias name for an already existing object. and any change to it will affect the reffered-to object. Thus what I see here is that `i` and `refI` are the same so modifying the same object (`i`) more than once here in the same expression.
- But Why all the compilers treat statement 2 as a well-defined behavior?
- What about statement 3 (ptrI)?

Comment: The compiler is not required to detect this Undefined Behaviour.  See _"..., more than one modifications of the same scalar in an expression..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @RichardCritten: Yes. But why it detects the first statement complaining (issing sequence point) but not about 2 and 3?

Comment: Just because it can (in some cases) does mean it is required to.  This compiler is just trying to do it's best.

Comment: @Maestro Try substituting `i` with `refI` and `*ptrI` to observe different warnings.

Comment: @Ron: Yes. I'll try

Comment: Also think about the ABI barrier, e.g. if there are two functions in two different libraries. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/37Fw2v). How should the compiler detect this? Even the return value of `bar` is unexpected if you look at the assembly.

Comment: I added the C++17 tag because I trust walnut that the behavior of the code changed with that version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of them have undefined behavior before C++17 and all have well-defined behavior since C++17.

Note that you are *not* modifying `i` more than once in either example. You are modifying it only with the increment.

However, it is also undefined behavior to have a side effect on one scalar (here the increment of `i`) be unsequenced with a value computation (here the left-hand use of `i`). Whether the side effect is produced by directly acting on the variable or through a reference or pointer does not matter.

Before C++17, the `<<` operator did not imply any sequencing of its operands, so the behavior is undefined in all your examples.

Since C++17, the `<<` operator is guaranteed to evaluate its operands from left-to-right. C++17 also extended the sequencing rules for operators to overloaded operators when called with the operator notation. So in all your examples the behavior is well-defined and the left-hand use of `i` is evaluated *first*, before `i`'s value is incremented.

Note however, that some compilers didn't implement these changes to the evaluation rules very timely, so even if you use the `-std=c++17` flag, it might still unfortunately violate the expected behavior with older and current compiler versions.

In addition, at least in the case of GCC, the `-Wsequence-point` warning is explicitly documented to warn even for behavior that became well-defined in C++17, to help the user to avoid writing code that would have undefined behavior in C and earlier C++ versions, see [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

The compiler is not required (and not able to) diagnose all cases of undefined behavior. In some simple situations it will be able to give you a warning (which you can turn into an error using `-Werror` or similar), but in more complex cases it will not. Still, your program will loose any guarantee on its behavior if you have undefined behavior, whether diagnosed or not.

Comment: But why he first statement is UB when compiled with gcc HEAD-10 or clang HEAD 11 and using C++2a(GNU)?

Comment: Do you mean now in the new standard the number of operators that guarantee the order of evaluation of their operands is 5? `&& || , ?` and `<<` ?

Comment: Would you mind to take a look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub  and running my first statement there?

Comment: @Maestro There are even more now. See the *(since C++17)* section on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules). In particular also `[]`, `.*`, `->*`, `>>`, `=`, `+=`, etc.

Comment: I get this running my program on cppreference: `warning: operation on 'i' may be undefined[-Wsequence - point]` but only about the first statement (`cout << i << ++i`).

Comment: @Maestro As I said, the compilers have not implemented all the changes correctly. See e.g. [this GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91415) related to your example.

Comment: Thank you get it now.

Comment: @walnut: Given `extern int x,arr[10],f(void);` gcc and clang process `arr[x] = f();` and `arr[f()]=x;` in opposite fashion, with gcc processing the array subscript before the right-hand operand of the assignment operator and clang processing it after.  Is the array subscript computation not part of the value computation or side-effect of the left-hand operand to the equality operator?

Comment: @supercat gcc is wrong if this is for C++17 or later. The right-hand side of the assignment must be evaluated (including side effects) before either `arr` or the array subscript is evaluated.

Comment: @supercat There is already a (still open) bug report [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84322). Before C++17 both compilers are correct, given that the evaluation order was indeterminate.

Comment: @walnut: I find it curious that the C++ Committee decided to change the rules to force compilers to generate less efficient code than should be necessary (and also curious that gcc aggressively "optimizes" in ways that could be expected to make a lot of useful code unreliable, but doesn't bother exploiting the unspecified evaluation order to improve code generation of `arr[x] = f();` by deferring the evaluation of `x` until it won't need to be held across a function call.

Comment: @supercat I guess they preferred safer code to faster code or at least didn't see enough evidence that these changes impede optimization much (which your example of gcc not actually fully making use of its freedom seems to validate). You can read the rationale in [p0145r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf), it has an example of an order-of-evaluation bug written and reviewed by experts that went unnoticed. I could not find the vote results on this, so I don't know whether they were mostly in favor of this or whether there was significant opposition.

Comment: @walnut: They say they didn't find any impediment to optimization, but it doesn't look like they examined many platforms.  IMHO, the proper remedy should be for the Committee to seek out places where code relies upon things not mandated by the Standard, recognize them as optional features, provide ways ways for programmers to explicitly demand such semantics when needed, and then deprecate reliance upon the behaviors without explicit demands for them.

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation rules are defined in terms of **objects**, not references or pointers, or whatever method you take to obtain the object.

That said, your three examples are exactly equivalent in terms of the order of evaluation rules (if we are only considering the object defined as `i`).

Hence let's just look at your first example:

```cpp
std::cout << i << ", " << ++i << std::endl;
```

For simplicity we can ignore the `", "` and `std::endl`, hence:

```cpp
std::cout << i << ++i;
```

[image]

- VC(X) = Value computation of X
- SE(X) = Side effects of X
- Exec(X) = The execution of the function body of X
- X <--- Y = X is sequenced after Y

Since c++ 11 and until c++ 17, this is undefined behavior because the side effects of D (see the graph) is unsequenced relative to the value calculation of C. However, both involves object `i`. This is undefined behavior.

Since c++ 17, there is an extra guarantee (on the `<<` and `>>` expressions) that both the value computation and side effects of C will be sequenced before the value computation and side effects of D (marked by the dotted lines), therefore the code becomes well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

All of these result in Undefined Behaviour.  Just because a compiler doesn't give a warning doesn't make it not so. Anything can happen with UB: it works, it works sometimes, it crashes, it blows up your computer, *&c*.

Comment: Yes thank you. My guesses were really correct then!

Comment: Thank you so much again! This has embarrassed me too much until you made it clear now.

Comment: This is only correct until C++17. Since C++17 the `<<` operator is fully sequenced.

Comment: @walnut: You mean "this only incorrect" or correct?

Comment: @Maestro walnut means "This answer is correctly calling the code incorrect only  until C++17". Since C++17 the code is correct, and hence this answer is not.